# Angular class method giving error: Not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a method on a class in my Angular 6 application and it's not working

I have the following Angular class;

```
export class Report {
    reportNumber: number;
    reportType: string;

    reportName(): string {
        return `${this.reportType} ${this.reportNumber}`;
    }
}
```

In my component I'm trying to do the following:

```
export class ReportsIndexComponent implements OnInit {    
    reports: Report[];

    constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.reportService.getReportsForJob(this.jobId)
        .pipe(first())
        .subscribe(
          result => {
            this.reports = result;
          },
          () => { });
    }
  }
```

My html looks like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let report of reports">                    
    {{report.reportName()}}
</p>
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.reportName is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **you don't have a class instance**, so the method `reportName()` isn't available

`report` is not a class instance of the class `Report`

In your template, instead of `{{report.reportName()}}`

**use:**

`{{report.reportType + ' ' + report.reportNumber}}`

Comment: Ok, how do I make report a class instance?

Comment: You could try something like: `.pipe(map(rep => new Report(rep.reportNumber, rep.reportType)))` in your service.